# Merge objects that share a common value in D3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have imported data from a CSV and would like to merge data from a different dataset using a shared value.

A method is outlined [here](http://learnjsdata.com/combine_data.html) but I am struggling to get it working myself

// New data to be added

```
var newdata = [{
 'starting point': 'Berkner Island', 'color': '#0084B5',
 'path': 'M 210.256,185.116'
}, {
 'starting point': 'Hercules Inlet', 'color': '#E48428',
 'path': 'M 156.355,241.624'
...
}];
```

// Explorer data from CSV

```
,,Name,First names,s,r,Nat,born,starting point,starting date,arrival date,days,km,Assist,Support,Style,note,
1,1,KAGGE,Erling,,,Nor,1/15/1963,Berkner Island,11/18/1992,1/7/1993,50,appr. 1300,n,n,solo,first solo unassisted,
2,2,ARNESEN,Liv,f,,Nor,6/1/1953,Hercules Inlet,11/4/1994,12/24/1994,50,1130,n,n,solo,first woman unassisted,
3,3,HAUGE,Odd Harald,,,Nor,1956,Berkner Island,11/4/1994,12/27/1994,54,appr. 1300,n,n,,,
```

// Adapted code

```
d3.csv("explorer.csv", function(explorer) {
  console.log(explorer);
});


explorer.forEach(function(explorer) {
  var result = newdata.filter(function(newdat) {
    return newdat['starting point'] === explorer.newdat['starting point'];
  });
  delete explorer.newdat['starting point'];
  explorer.newdat = (result[0] !== undefined) ? result[0].name : null;
});
```

[Full code here](https://plnkr.co/edit/u9bK7Ia2VFfnOYU4SekG?p=info)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `new` is a reserved word so don't use `function(new)`

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explorer.foreach statement will throw an error that `explorer is not defined` due to it existing outside of the d3.csv function.

I'm assuming you want to add the color and path where the starting points match. You need to add the foreach into the d3.csv function like so.

```
d3.csv("explorer.csv", function(explorer) {

  explorer.forEach(function(exp) {
    var result = newdata.filter(function(newd) {
      return exp['starting point'] === newd['starting point'];
    });
    exp.color = (result[0] !== undefined) ? result[0].color : null;
    exp.path = (result[0] !== undefined) ? result[0].path : null;
  });
  console.log(explorer);
});
```

[updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/71H9idmoL4H8K2SeWt4E?p=preview)